# Caret-like figure using CSS to demonstrate selected tab

Tags: css

How to create a the selected state for the "Dashboard" tab using CSS? more specifically this figure:

```
|
>
|
```

[image: screenshot]

I know it's possible to create caret using CSS like http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ but the selected/active state above is different. Is such design possible to achieve using CSS (the empty caret `>`)?

Comment: Why not just use an image of a caret as the background image?

Comment: @David, I thought about it, but I'm trying to use css as much as possible and avoid using images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily by placing a `div` inside each sub box and by using `position: relative` with `left: 100%` to move it out of the box. E.G.

If your bar is set up like:

```
<div id="bar">
    <div class="box" id="child1"> 
        <div class="triangle"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="child2"> 
        <div class="triangle"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="child3"> 
        <div class="triangle"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you style things like:

```
.box {
    width: 50px;               /* 50 x 50 pixel size boxes. */
    height: 50px;              /* 50 x 50 pixel size boxes. */
    background-color: #bdc3c7; /* Arbitrary background color */
}

.box[selected="true"] {
    background-color: #27ae60; /* Selected box color */
}

.box[selected="true"] > .triangle {
   border-left-color: #27ae60; /* Make sure this color is the same as the above one */
}

.triangle {
    position: relative;        /* Used to move the triangle "out" of the parent */
    top: calc(50% - 10px);     /* For centering, the -10px is to make up for the border */
    left: 100%;                /* Move the box completely out of the parent */
    /* Create Triangle */
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;

    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Doing this should give you something like: http://jsfiddle.net/BD4f3/1/

In this example I'm letting you set all this with an attribute on any box.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd give this a shot since I've done a couple of triangles before, but haven't done much with opacity.

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/Xw5K3/) has a "button", over which a div with an arrow is placed with absolute positioning. The opacity of the "arrow-box" allows you to see the underlying box.

I suppose one could move the arrow-box around with jQuery, covering up various buttons that are selected.

Here is the part of the CSS that makes the arrow:
CSS

```
.testdiv:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid yellow;
    top: 40px;
    right: -25px;
}
```

Nice exercise for me. Thanks for the question!

Edit: If you hide the covering element with display:none, you can hover over the button and change it to display: block.